# convert python request to PHP-cURL equivalent

Tags: php, python, curl

I am sending a POST request to a URL. It works correctly in python but in php-curl, I always get a bad request error (i.e. my POST data is not as expected by the server)

Python code: (works correctly. 200 OK)

```
import httplib, urllib, json

def SendRequest(param1):
    url = "api.xyz.com"
    body = {"version": "1.0", "data":[{"param1":param1, "age":35}]}
    jsonBody = json.dumps(body)

    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json",
               "Accept": "application/json; charset=utf8"}
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
    conn.request("POST", "/api/?client_id=xx-xx-xx", jsonBody, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
```

php-cURL code (does not work. 406 Bad request error)

```
function sendCurlRequest($param1)
{
    $payload = preparePayload($param1); 
    $url = "http://api.xyz.com/api/?client_id=xx-xx-xx"; 
    $jsonResponse = executePOSTRequest($url, $payload);
    $response = json_decode($jsonResponse);
}

function preparePayload($param1)
{
    $payload = array("version" = "1.0",
                     "data" => array(array("param1" => $param1,
                                           "age" => 35
                                          )
                                    ),
                    );

    $jsonPayload = json_encode($payload);
    return $jsonPayload;
}

function executePOSTRequest($url, $payload)
{
    $newlines = array("\r", "\n", " ");
    $url = str_replace($newlines, '', $url);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS,array('Content-Type:application/json; Accept: application/json; charset=utf8'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

I know there is some mistake in my use of cURL. Please suggest.

Update: Use of double array in php is because server expects the JSON string (POST payload) in this format

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"data":
[{"param1":name, "age":35},{"param1":name,"age":60}]
}
```

In python, I am using list of dict; in php I think it is array of arrays only.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is that the original Python code is sending a pure JSON body, and the PHP version is posting the various values as POST fields. I don't know how to send a pure JSON body but I'm sure the answer is somewhere here on SO

Comment: Pekka, thx fo your comment but I think in both cases, I am sending a JSON string as POST data. Do you mean that in php, my JSON string is being broken into pieces and each field sent as form-fields? that cannot be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like this, I find that it's always better to look at what goes over the wire instead of trying to puzzle out what might be wrong with the code.

My advice:

- Create a little test server using  the python `BaseHTTPServer` and
  derive a class from
  `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` that doesn't
  do anything but provide an override
  of the `do_POST` method
- Your `do_POST` should just dump the
  headers and POST body it receives to
  file
- Point your code samples at this
  little test server and then diff the
  files that it creates. I'm guessing
  that if the answer isn't immediately
  obvious, you'll at the very least get
  one or more useful clues to stomp
  this problem out.

Comment: Thanks for the sound advice. It will be of great help in future problems as well. Finally, I did a POST to local server through php and python and compared the differences in headers and data. I was making some mistakes in using curl. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it causes your problem, but I do see a difference between the two:
In the python code you send two header lines:  Content-Type  and Accept.  While  in the PHP code, they are a single line.

Comment: no, that does not cause a problem. I have wrestled with curl for quite a long time. I have tried sending Content-Type and Accept as two separate lines. No difference.

Comment: Ok, are you also aware that the option should be named: CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  without the S at the end? So:

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type:application/json;','Accept: application/json; charset=utf8'));

Comment: Hey, Michielvv, nice catch. I did not notice the extra 'S'. When I did a POST to local server, only then I saw it in apache error log. Thanks. :-)
Also, as you said, Content-Type and Accept should be different elements in array. Merging them as a single line is WRONG. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parameter index - cURL POST fields need to be sent as a query string or as an array.

Either:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'payload=' . urlencode($payload));
```

Or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('payload' => $payload));
```

Replace `payload` with the name of the parameter expected by the API to hold the JSON string.

If the endpoint API is not expecting a parameter, then it should work - it just won't appear in the POST array in your test script. You can fetch the body of the POST contents using

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: yes, I have got your point. But in python, I am not using any parameter to hold JSON string. Also, the API docs do not mention any such parameter. All it mentions is "format the request as JSON string and submit it as POST data to given URL". Is this cURL limitation?

Comment: In that case, it should've worked as you've written it before. Did you try it with the actual API or just with your testing script? I added a way for you to test direct POST content with the $_POST array

Comment: yes, Eran. thanks. I was following the advice of bgporter to post on local server through php and python and check the difference between the two. That's how I got into empty _POST problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060345/post-is-empty-in-php

Comment: My API is working fine now. I was checking response header through get_header($url, 1) php function. And it was always returning 406 error. The correct way is to use "curl_getinfo($ch)". It gives 200 ok. Another mistake was as pointed by  Michielvv. (using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER instead of HEADERS :) )